How to bundle pandas rows together using the opposite of pandas.groupby-methodology
I have the following pandas.DataFrame
   match_id  court
0  50311513      1
1  50313011      2
2  50313009      2
3  50317691      1
4  50315247      2
5  50318597      1
6  50318877      1
7  50318983      1
8  50318831      1
9  50318595      1

As you can see there are a total of 2 courses. I want to bundle each "slot" together.
So, the first grouped df should contain match 50311513 and 50313011. The second slot should contain 50313009 and 50317691. After the third slot, the grouped df is basically a single row.
How can I tell pandas.groupby() that only one match can be played on the course?
Thanks
Edit
Different input data:
     match_id  court  group
0    46768193      1     0
1    46768193      1     1
2    46768187      2     0
3    46768187      2     1
4    46767821      3     0


IIUC, you can form two successive groups with cumcount:
# start new group on identical values
g1 = df['court'].eq(df['court'].shift()).cumsum()
# in the previous groups, restart if the value was already seen
g2 = df['court'].groupby([df['court'], g1]).cumcount()

df['group'] = df.groupby([g1, g2]).ngroup()

# variant
# df['group'] = (g1.diff().ne(0)|g2.diff().ne(0)).cumsum().sub(1)

Output:
   match_id  court  group
0  50311513      1      0
1  50313011      2      0
2  50313009      2      1
3  50317691      1      1
4  50315247      2      2
5  50318597      1      2
6  50318877      1      3
7  50318983      1      4
8  50318831      1      5
9  50318595      1      6

Intermediates:
   match_id  court  g1  g2  group
0  50311513      1   0   0      0
1  50313011      2   0   0      0
2  50313009      2   1   0      1
3  50317691      1   1   0      1
4  50315247      2   1   1      2
5  50318597      1   1   1      2
6  50318877      1   2   0      3
7  50318983      1   3   0      4
8  50318831      1   4   0      5
9  50318595      1   5   0      6

generalization
If you need to handle more groups, you could go with a custom (iterative) function with a set to keep track of the already seen items. If the set of past seen items already contains the current item, start a new group:
def grouper(s):
    S = set()
    group = []
    n = 0
    for val in s:
        if val in S:
            n += 1
            S = {val}
        else:
            S.add(val)
        group.append(n)
    return group

df['group'] = grouper(df['court'])

Example:
    match_id  court  group
0   50311513      1      0
1   50313011      2      0
2   50313012      3      0
3   50313009      2      1
4   50317691      1      1
5   50315247      2      2
6   50315248      3      2
7   50318597      1      2
8   50318877      1      3
9   50318983      1      4
10  50319873      3      4
11  50318831      1      5
12  50318595      1      6


I added another sample where your suggestion doesn't work on. Any idea how to adjust your solution?

Made it work using: def grouper(s: pd.Series) -> List[int]:
groups = []
courts = set(s.unique())
n = defaultdict(int, {c: 0 for c in courts})

for v in s:
    n[v] += 1

    groups.append(n[v])

return groups


@HJA24 looks like a df.groupby('court').cumcount() to me.
